# How to find deprecated line in Gradle file in android?

Tags: android, build.gradle

While Building I'm getting a warning like

```
The following project options are deprecated and have been removed:
```

But Nothing removed from my project. Because of deprecated lines, some functionalities are not working properly. Please Help me to find out deprecated lines from Gradle.

in java or Kotlin file, deprecated lines are highlighted. is there any way to highlight in Gradle file also?

[click to view image about warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKzUq.png)

Comment: can you paste the complete error line. there must be something clearly written, what has been removed

Comment: android studio showing the following project options. but below noting is mentioned